# "Cannot get base site config" error in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are using Multi-Site setup in Spartacus. It works fine, however when user enters URL with incorrect baseSite, Spartacus shows a blank page and throws an error in JS console `Error: Cannot get base site config! Current url (https://www.example.com/xyz/) doesn't match any of url patterns of any base sites.` (`xyz` is the incorrect baseSite identifier in this example).

Is there a way to handle this error and redirect user e.g. to 404 not found page in this case?

Comment: Does the accepted answer work for you?

Comment: @ushaikh Yes, as far as I remember this approach worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement your own class based on `SiteContextConfigInitializer` and override the method `resolveConfig`. Then add it to providers in your module: `{ provide: SiteContextConfigInitializer, useClass: YourSiteContextConfigInitializer }`. Unfortunatelly I guess you must add also own methods for `isCurrentBaseSite` and `get currentUrl` (just copy and rename) because they are private.